# C++ class method to return different types

Tags: c++

I have a method in a class that returns a vector of strings. Simple enough. But say sometimes I want the entire string to come back, unparsed? But using the same method.

Since the method that gets the data is pretty complex, I currently use the method to return the raw string, then parse it in into a vector in main if have to. Or if wanted to could duplicate the method with just a different return type.

Is there a more elegant way to do this using one method?

Comment: It's a bit ugly, but some structure that can accommodate both types? What you're describing here sounds like a failure in the design stage, so I'd keep working until you avoid the issue altogether.

Comment: @tadman unions don't work with constructors, you can use them only with POD

Comment: Here are no 'elegant solution'. You will need to test in other places the result type of function, i.e. is are string or is are vector of string to process further

Comment: When you say that you `want the entire string to come back`, does that mean that your method takes a string and parses it into a vector of strings?

Comment: @sashoalm that's only true in C++03.

Comment: P.S. Just do two separate functions, you can implement one from other.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, right after posting this, I figured out how to do it. Make the complex method that gets the data private, set up two public methods that call it, and return the different types.  The point was to keep the conversion from set of string to vector out of main. Will hide in the class.

Sometimes it helps to talk about problems. Working on this alone, and no one to talk to.

Thanks guys, believe it or not, you helped without even knowing it. :)

Comment: This is not a forum, however. This is the wrong place if you just want to have a conversation, even if it's for programming. You should try the chat rooms for that.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not possible to have two functions with the same name which only differ by return type. In a narrow sense I see the following main possibilities to work around that limitation:

- A general solution for this kind of problem is to have references as arguments which are changed as a side effect of the function. The actual return value is a simple bool or integer indicating success. Here you would pass a reference to an initially empty vector; whether the string was parsed and split or not would be indicated by a boolean return value, and the results of the parsing -- if it happened -- would be put in the referenced vector.
- Return a vector as before; an empty vector would indicate that no parsing happened. This solution implies that the raw string is accessible by the caller, for example because obtaining the string and parsing it were separated in two functions.

In a wider sense this is just a design problem, as you just detected. You can obtain, inspect, and -- only if the inspection indicates that it's necessary --  parse the data in separate steps so that you know which function to call and what to do with the data at every point. Divide et impera, the Tao of programming.

Comment: It is possible to have two functions differing only by return type, the compiler just can't automatically choose between them. Just define one implementation as a template function, templated on the return type. Then define a specialization for the other return type with a different implementation.

Comment: This is horrible and **should** never be done.

Comment: @joelw Are you referring to one of my suggestions? If so, which one, and why do you find it horrible?

Comment: I was referring to my suggestion.

Comment: @joelw Ah! I see :-) I hadn't even realized that the first comment was from you as well. Your suggestion is interesting though. I guess it's an ontological problem whether two template instantiations which must be explicitly chosen are considered one function or two ;-) (Like `f<int>()` vs. `f<float>()`.)